# Python Dictionary From Lambda Github Webhook Event Failing to Lookup Key Value

Tags: python, dictionary, github

I have an AWS Lambda that is sitting behind a API Gateway and taking POST requests from GitHub on Pull Requests. I'm trying to process the Payload so that I can make decisions based on the Pull Request status.

My issue is that I'm not able to get the dictionary key value. This is a slimmed down version of the dictionary that I'm getting in the Event variable of the Lambda (the payload from GitHub):

```
dict = {'version': 2.0, 'routeKey': 'POST /', 'body': '{"action": "synchronize","number": 1,"pull_request": {"url":"https://myurl.com"}'}
print(dict['body']['action'])
```

I need to get the value of the pull_request url. I get the following when I try to process the dictionary:

```
print(dict['version'])  # 2.0
print(dict['body']['pull_request']['url'])  #TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Why is there a single quote in the dictionary that is preventing me from accessing keys and values?

How can I get the value of the pull request url from this key?

Comment: Well I've worked with Lambda and API gateway responses before, and the reason definitely is that `body` is always passed in as a JSON string. You'd need to first load this into a Python dict object, via `json.loads`, in order to access the data within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `dict['body']` is a string not a dictionary, you have to convert that to a dictionary before you can access.

Also it seems to be a malformed JSON string, missing a closing `'}'`

```
{"action": "synchronize","number": 1,"pull_request": {"url":"https://myurl.com"}
```

If you fix that you can then use `json.loads`

```
from json import loads

event = {'version': 2.0, 'routeKey': 'POST /', 'body': '{"action": "synchronize","number": 1,"pull_request": {"url":"https://myurl.com"}}'}

print(loads(event['body'])['pull_request']['url'])
```